# codeigniter retrieve data from database normal print_r working fine but can't use foreach why

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord, codeigniter-2

I am going to fetch specific gender from db like  gender='male' code is working fine but can't iterate it in foreach why it is

model you can check

```
 class get_all_gender extends CI_Model {
        //put your code here
        public function select_male() {
            $this->db->select('*');
            $this->db->from('bride_groom_register');
             $this->db->where("gender='male'");
            $query = $this->db->get();
            if ($query->result() > 0) 
           {
                return $query;
            } else {
                return FALSE;
            }
        }

    }
```

and controller i m getting data from database

```
class Welcome extends CI_Controller {


    public function index()
    {
            $this->load->model('get_all_gender');

            $data['res']=$this->get_all_gender->select_male();
            $this->load->view('list',$data);

        }
}
```

simple view

```
foreach ($res as $row)
{
    echo $row->name;

}
```

Comment: Could you please accept the answer that worked for you?

Answer (score 1):

You should return the `$query`'s `result()` instead of `$query` itself. Your model should look like this:

```
class Get_all_gender extends CI_Model {//put your code here

    public function select_male() {
        $this->db->where("gender","male");
        $query = $this->db->get("bride_groom_register");

        if ($query->num_rows() > 0)  {

            return $query->result();
        } else {

            return FALSE;
        }
    }
}
```

You are saving the result in the controller:

```
$data['res'] = $this->get_all_gender->select_male();
```

So you can access it like this in the view:

```
if($res !== FALSE){
  foreach ($res as $row)
  {
      echo $row->name;
  }
}
```

You should check for the FALSE condition, otherwise the view will throw PHP errors when there is no rows returned from the model.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

**In Model**

```
class get_all_gender extends CI_Model {
    //put your code here
    public function select_male() 
    {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('bride_groom_register');
        $this->db->where("gender='male'");
        $query = $this->db->get();
        $result = $query->result_array();

        if (!empty($result)) 
        {
            return $result;
        } 
        else {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
}
```

**In Controller**

```
class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->model('get_all_gender');

        $data['res']    =   $this->get_all_gender->select_male();
        $this->load->view('list',$data);
    }
}
```

**In View**

```
if ($res != FALSE) {
    foreach ($res as $value) {
        echo $value;
    }
} 
else {
    echo "Seleted Category is Empty";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try code below on model

Class Name first letter upper case

Filename: **Get_all_gender.php**

```
<?php

class Get_all_gender extends CI_Model {//put your code here

    public function select_male() {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('bride_groom_register');
        $this->db->where('gender', 'male');
        $query = $this->db->get();

        if ($query->num_rows() > 0)  {

            return $query->result_array();

            // Or 

            // return $query->row_array();

        } else {

            return FALSE;

        }
    }

}
```

On View

```
foreach ($res as $row)
{
    echo $row['name'];

}
```

Comment: if i got 15 reputation then my vote will be consider i m new here

Comment: You can click on the tick to accept a answer it does not matter how many rep you have.

Answer (score 0):

Class Name first letter upper case

```
class Get_all_gender extends CI_Model {//put your code here

    public function select_male() {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('bride_groom_register');
        $this->db->where("gender='male'");
        $query = $this->db->get();

        if ($query->num_rows() > 0)  {

            return $query->result_array();

        } else {

            return FALSE;

        }
    }

}
```